# known_hosts file for WinSCP?

Tags: ssh, sftp, winscp

Is there a way in WinSCP to configure a `known_hosts` file with key fingerprints so as to not be queried by WinSCP when you want to connect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WinSCP does not use `known_hosts` file. Like PuTTY, it stores known host keys into Windows registry (or optionally an INI file)

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\SshHostKeys]
```

The format of the keys is different to that of `known_hosts`.

If you have the host key cached on another machine, you can copy it over to the new machine.

---

But you can [import the host keys from the `known_hosts` file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_import).

---

Another way is to have WinSCP save new site with a known fingerprint of the host key, like:

```
winscp.exe sftp://username;fingerprint=ssh-rsa-xxxxxxxxxxx...=@example.com/;save
```

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_url#save